# Return statement inside a closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

Do following return statements have any significance inside closure. Do they return as intended?

```
fetchAPI() { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        // Print error
        return
    } else {
        if result?.data != nil {
            if (result?.success)! {
                // Do stuff
            }
        } else {
            // Print error
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please explain, what "...have any significance inside closure" means? Anyway, the 1st part of the code is clear: If there is an error, handle it. And in the 2nd part it seems, that result can be successfull (do stuff) or not (error). So far, so good. But what means "any significance"?

Comment: What happened when you ran the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they have no significance.

Both `return` statements are redundant and can be omitted. And a `return` statement in a closure exits the closure, not the function.

Comment: Tx, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are other Swift flow control statements that can make your code a lot more readable in place of nested-ifs.

```
fetchAPI() { result, error in
    // Check that error is nil
    guard error == nil else {
        // print error
        return
    }

    // Check that result is not nil and result.success is true
    guard let result = result, result.success else {
        // print error
        return
    }

    // Now you have a valid response. Do something with it
}
```